# Registering types in a chain of classes

Tags: c#, autofac

Let's say we have the following inheritance tree:

```
Base<Generic> : Base : IBase
```

And Have two kinds of implementations:

```
A) Class1Operation : Base<Generic>
   Class2Operation : Base<Generic>

B) Class3Operation : Base
   Class4Operation : Base
```

For point A I have something like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Operation"))
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(Base<>))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

How Can i register types for point B so all of them (A and B) I could resolve by interface: IBase?

**EDIT**

I managed to do that by adding next registerAssemblyTypes method:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(persistenceAssembly)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Operation"))
        .AssignableTo<Base>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and ... seems to resolve references in both examples.

Comment: How do you expect autofac to inject different (derived) classes based solely on the `IBase` type of the injected dependency?

Comment: Look at edited post

Comment: This is a useful question and answer. It would be even better if you edited the title to more clearly reflect what you're trying to do so that the next person who needs it can find it.

Comment: @ScottHannen  Can you propose a title, nothing is coming to me head right now ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solved my problem:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(persistenceAssembly)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Operation"))
        .AssignableTo<Base>()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```